# When does a linear equation have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of $k$ the equation $(k+8)x-3k = 3k(1-x)-6$ has infinitely many solutions?

Since this is not a set of linear equations you can't use the augmented matrix and Gaussian elimination, how would you solve this?

Comment: On the contrary, this is a linear equation in $x$.

Comment: Yes it is a linear equation once $k$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The equation with variable $x$ is given by
$$
x(4k + 8) - 6(k + 1)=0.
$$
For $k=-2$ it has no solution over a field of characteristic zero, hence we may divide by $4k+8$ to obtain a unique solution for $x$. In particular, the equation never has infinitely many solutions.